# How to use offset in strategies

Tags: pine-script, offset

I want to use three moving averages in one indicator, but one of the moving averages has offset in its inputs. I can not use plotshape in the way that I want.
Version 5 pine script:

```
indicator("Kestrel", overlay = true)

ma1 = ta.sma (close, 5)
ma2 = ta.sma (close, 14)
ma3 = ta.sma (close, 200)

plot (ma1, color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
plot (ma2, color = color.blue, linewidth = 2, offset = 3)
plot (ma3, color = color.lime, linewidth = 2)
```

How can I use plotshape and omit plots from my indicator.? Thnxs

Comment: can you elaborate? Do you want to delete `, offset = 3`?

Comment: For example, whenever ma1 crosses ma2, I want to show a triangle on the chart. So I need to use this code:
'longSignal = ta.crossover (ma1, ma2)
plotshape (longSignal, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar'
but the problem is this: In my strategy, ma2 needs offset, But I can not use the offset function in plotshape.